# Control The Number Columns in a jquery Datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I’m using jQuery Datatables to create a table with 500 rows and one column. However I’d like to have jQuery increase the number of columns displayed to cut down on paging through the table. Ideally I’d like to have 10 rows of 10 columns. That way the user would only need to navigate through 10 pages.

I don’t want to have to deal with increasing the number of columns in the server side code; it would be much easier for me to just write out 500 rows and have jquery control the number of columns displayed. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to reduce the paging size?share any code you have used..

Comment: I want to carry on writing out 500 rows to the datatable, each with one table cell, and I want to be able to control the number of columns displayed - with jQuery. I know how to modify the iDisplayLength parameter in the datatable definition, but that simply changes the number of rows. I'd like to be able to increase the number of columns with jQuery.

Comment: Do you have some code you can show us?  You mentioned server side code, are you doing server side filtering as well?  Depending on how you are getting the data from the server, this could be simple to accomplish.